# Label not hide even the value is false with C#

Tags: c#, menu, textbox, hide, visible

I have strange issue with my medical application coding with C#. I got a function which hides some functionality of the menu according the profile. For example a medical assistant shouldn't access to user creation, and so one. Now when I try to hide `Label`, or a `TextBox` with `Label.Visible = false;` using the function or even in the form load, nothing is hidden.

Below is my function:

```
private void LoadMenu(string mySession)
{            
    switch (mySession)
    {
        case "Secretaire":
            BtnCaisse.Visible = false;
            BtnPharmacie.Visible = false;
            BtnParametrage.Visible = false;
            BtnLaboratoire.Visible = false;
            UserChildNouveau.Visible = false;
            break;

        case "Administrateur":
            BtnPharmacie.Visible = false;
            BtnLaboratoire.Visible = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged this with the step debugger? It might not be hitting your code... For instance switch is case sensitive.

Comment: Hi, will you explain me how to use the step debugger. I know too swich is case sensitive

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2019

Comment: and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/autos-and-locals-windows?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

Based on @the-generals comment, you could avoid a capitalization error by setting everything to upper or lower case:

```
private void LoadMenu(string mySession)
{
    switch (mySession.ToUpper())
    {
        case "SECRETAIRE":
            BtnCaisse.Visible = false;
            BtnPharmacie.Visible = false;
            BtnParametrage.Visible = false;
            BtnLaboratoire.Visible = false;
            UserChildNouveau.Visible = false;
            break;

        case "ADMINISTRATEUR":
            BtnPharmacie.Visible = false;
            BtnLaboratoire.Visible = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Notice that I used `ToUpper()` in the `switch` parameter and the case statements are upper case too.

For debugging, Visual Studio lets you click in the gutter (the left hand margin in the editor) to set a break point. You'll know it when you see the big red dot in the gutter. When you hit F5, VS will stop at that breakpoint. Then you can go to the Autos, Locals, or Watch windows (or just hover over the variable) to see what the value of `mySession` is. You can also step through code after hitting a breakpoint:

- F10 steps over
- F11 steps into a method

There's more and it's worth your time to dig into how the debugger works because it will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Hi Joe, Thanks you for your advise but I already try to make a break point on the LoadMenu() function and the value of mySession is null. Also when create a TextBox on my form, and set it on the form_load the value of Visible to false, ie TextBox1.Visible = false; the field is not hided

Comment: You said "mySession is null", which is the reason why none of the case blocks ran. Now, use the debugger to learn why mySession was null, when it should have contained one of the two values in the switch statement.